How can I set Transaction Fee on .net project with Solnet nuget package
I use the Solnet nuget package on my .net application and I cannot assign a custom fee value for any token transfer or sol transfer in this package. After this process, it automatically gives the fee value as 0.000005 SOL. And the token transfers I sent cannot be found on the network, and I think the reason for this is the low fee amount. I have never encountered a manual fee assignment method in the Solnet nuget package.
var transactionBuilder = new TransactionBuilder()
                     .SetRecentBlockHash(recentBlockHash.Result.Value.Blockhash)
                     .SetFeePayer(fromAccount)
                     .AddInstruction(TokenProgram.Burn(
                         fromAssociatedTokenAccount,
                         receiverAssociatedTokenAccount,
                         100000,
                         fromAccount
                     ));


Does this answer your question? How to increase the Transaction Fee on SolNet (.net)

@JonC Doesn't answer fully. Because the solnet version I use does not contain ComputeBudgetProgram or anything related to it.

Solnet has no more support since 2 years. However someone added a commit few months ago regarding your issue. https://github.com/bmresearch/Solnet/commit/21fdbcee0e90d59c8eef5391fe72f2546791211a. But nuget packages aren't uptodate
